# being author of a paper

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, differences

I have a question, regarding authorship in a publication.

A colleague of mine who is a biologist (from a different group) received the second revision of her/his paper and in the revision it's been asked to do Anova in order to illustrate the significant change between 4 groups.

I don't want to sound like a cheeky person, but have no idea whether if I do it I should be included in the paper or I should just do it as if I'm doing it for a friend.

I have no access to my boss to consult this with him. 
I would appreciate your help to make this point clear to me.

Thanks!

Comment: I would rather ask this question on academia stackexchange, you can rather expect answers there. It differs a lot between institutions what is a minimum requirement to be an author of a publication. Also, if the paper is in the review process then it might be some rules from the journal regarding adding an author. You can also find similar [cases here](http://publicationethics.org/cases).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Academia Stack Exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My rule of thumb (that I read somewhere long ago, and forgot where) is whether or not a person made an ``intellectual contribution'', and if they did, they should be included.

In your case, that would imply you should be included.

However, in acadaemia it is seldon that easy, since there's a lot of politics involved..

However, the easiest thing for you could be to simply ask them if they'd consider including you as an author for your contribution to their paper.